# Compile subversion on CentOs

Tags: svn, centos5

I have downloaded, compiled and installed so far:
apr-1.3.9
apr-util-1.3.9
sqlite-3.6.23
zlib-1.2.4
libtool-2.2.6b

Now after downloading subversion-1.6.9, the config works fine but compiling it will end with the following error:

cd subversion/svn && /bin/sh /root/subversion-1.6.9/libtool --tag=CC --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2  -g -O2 -pthread   -rpath /usr/local/lib -o svn  add-cmd.o blame-cmd.o cat-cmd.o changelist-cmd.o checkout-cmd.o cleanup-cmd.o commit-cmd.o conflict-callbacks.o copy-cmd.o delete-cmd.o diff-cmd.o export-cmd.o help-cmd.o import-cmd.o info-cmd.o list-cmd.o lock-cmd.o log-cmd.o main.o merge-cmd.o mergeinfo-cmd.o mkdir-cmd.o move-cmd.o notify.o propdel-cmd.o propedit-cmd.o propget-cmd.o proplist-cmd.o props.o propset-cmd.o resolve-cmd.o resolved-cmd.o revert-cmd.o status-cmd.o status.o switch-cmd.o tree-conflicts.o unlock-cmd.o update-cmd.o util.o ../../subversion/libsvn_client/libsvn_client-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_wc/libsvn_wc-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_ra/libsvn_ra-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_delta/libsvn_delta-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_diff/libsvn_diff-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.la     -lexpat /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread -ldl

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/svn/svn] Error 1

The file at /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la exists and seems to be OK (from permission perspective

What could be the problem here?
Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about libexpat, not libapr. I guess you're missing Expat XML Parser - at least the linker is not able to find it. Check where libexpat is located in your system and perhaps you should give its path to configure script.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly the issue. I've downloaded and compiled the parser and all works now. Thanks